# What is the probability that you can get a straight?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Disclaimer: I am sure this question has been asked but I want to arrive to the answer on my own as it is important to first understand scenarios like this when first learning about Probability at the college level and really diving into the material. I encountered this question in an introductory reading and it has been rather irksome as I don't think the answer is so obvious.

Assuming the following: 
1) The game is 5 card stud (not sure if game mechanics affect probability, ie holdem?)
2) Aces don't count as ones, they are only counted after the king
3) Both Jokers are left out of the deck in this game

There are 10 possible different ways (sets) you can get a straight:

A,2,3,4,5

2,3,4,5,6

3,4,5,6,7

4,5,6,7,8

5,6,7,8,9

6,7,8,9,10

7,8,9,10,J

8,9,10,J,Q

9,10,J,Q,K

10,J,Q,K,A

There are 10 different sets and each set can be ordered $4^5$ different ways so to take into account all the possible straights: $\frac{4^5\times 10}{52!}$? But wait this just accounts for the suits correct?

The 4^5 is from the basic property that you multiply all the elements from one set by all the elements from another set when you want to find all the different combinations of the two sets. So this tells me all the different combinations of suits I believe. Now I need the orders of the cards. Which would be 5! in each set so more or less im thinking: $\frac{(4^5\times5!) \times (10)}{52!}$ is much closer? Mark said I'm close but I'm not sure where my error is. The denominator I think would be closer to $4^14 \times 14!$ (the number of orders of suits times the number of orders of rank)so up to this point I have:

$\frac{(4^5 \times 5!) \times (10)}{4^14 \times 14!}. Is there possibly a different relationship between the two (rank and suit) that might call for a different operation other than multiplication

Comment: Why do you say "each straight can happen $4$ different times"?  Are you only interested in straight flushes?  Otherwise, it's $4^5$.

Comment: Getting e.g. 2, 4, 3, 5, 6 is also a straight. You have only considered getting the cards the ascending order.

Comment: Its also standard that A2345 is a straight. If I recall correctly, it is called the wheel.

Comment: A low is a valid straight.  You are not accounting for the suits of the cards.  Each card can be a different suit.  But the biggie...you only care about how 5 cards in the deck are arranged, not the whole deck.

Comment: No when I said that that each straight can happen 4 different times I meant that there are 4 twos, 4 threes, 4 fours, 4 fives, and 4 sixes. so I could get 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D, 6D. Then 2S, 3C, 4S, 5D, 6S...and so on... So if I take into account the different orders then there are still 9 sets but then i have to take into account the orders of those sets as well which would be 5!+5!+....5!(of the ninth set) is that correct?

Comment: I mean the tenth set. Since a low does count. Im still trying to figure out what it means when I have four of each card in one set, I think I got it each set  can be ordered $4^5$ times. Would it work to take $4^5$ $\times 10$ to calculate all the possible straights? I haven't looked below because I still want to figure out the calculation from inferences alone.

Comment: Your numerator is nearly correct.  Your denominator is way off.

Comment: That is because I didn't take into suits in the denominator I am assuming? What is wrong with the numerator? The two things I have learned thus far is that I need to take into account: 1) The possible orders of suits 2) The possible orders of the cards. What I have taken away from this that applies to all situations is I need to identify all that can be ordered in different orders and account for them better. Which in this case are suits and rank. Is there a problem in the way I am combining the affect of the two in the numerator?

Comment: Would the denominator be closer with: the number of ranks: 14, the number of suits of each rank is 4. So now I have to figure out how they affect each other.

Comment: with the numerator, $10\times4^5$ is pretty close.  However, most people don't want to mix-up the straight flush with the straight or the flush.  Yes, the straight-flush is the intersection of straights and flushes, but since it ranks higher in the showdown better to say that they are not the same thing.  In the denominator.  How many 5 card poker hands are there?  52! is all 52 cards, not just the 5 in your hand.

Comment: You first say that "Aces don't count as ones, they are only counted after the king", but then count "$A$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$" as a straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A-low is a straight.

$10$ possible values for the lowest card.
$4^5$ possible arrangements of suits.
$(4^5-4)$ if you want to keep the straight-flush separate.

$10*(4^5-4) = 10200$ ways to make a straight.

$52 \choose 5$$=\dfrac{52!}{(52-5)!(5!)} = 2.6$ million possible hands.

$0.4\%$ chance of pulling a straight on 5 cards.

Comment: Thank you Doug. And this goes for all as well thanks for helping me see my error in modeling it and giving me hints to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Order doesn't matter, because A,2,3,4,5 is the same hand has 3,4,2,A,5.  So you want to stick with $4^5*10$ in your numerator. To consider straights independently from straight flushes, remove the 4 possible straight flushes from each of the 10 initial positions, giving you $(4^5-4)*10$.  This is done because a straight flush is much more valuable than a typical straight.

For the denominator, you should consider a random draw of your hand A,B,C,D,E.  You have 52 possibilities for card A, 51 possibilities for card B, etc. for $(52*51*50*49*48)$ possible combinations.  Another way of writing this is $\frac{52!}{47!}$.  But remember, we said order doesn't matter.  Just like you multiplied by $5!$ to account for the order of five cards, we will divide by $5!$ to discount the order, making your denominator $\frac{52!}{(5!)47!}$.